# Count the number of times a group of words appear in a text

Tags: python, text, count, nlp, word-count

I have 4 lists of words that categorise something and a tokenised text by word.

```
animals = ["cat", "dog", "fish"]
colours = ["blue", "red", "green"]
food = ["pasta", "chips", "beef"]
sport = ["football", "basketball", "tennis"]

text = ["Once","upon","a","time",.......]
```

I would like to count the number of occurrences of the words in these lists in a certain text but as a sum of the words for each list. Therefore the results would show an occurrence of 10 animal words, 20 colour words, 6 food words and 13 sport words across the whole text.

The data I'm actually working on is quite large, so anything that works quickly is required.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hey, I think the question is not clear enough. Please try to better define what is the general solution you are looking for, or maybe give a clearer and more complete example.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! So I have a long list of text with each word tokenised. I want to be able to count the number of 'animal' words that appear inside that text. Then I want to do the same for colours, the same for food and the same for sport. So in the end I can tell that the animal words appear more than the colour words within the text. Hope that makes sense

Comment: "Therefore the results would show...." why? We don't know what data you're working with... Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your categories to a `dict` of `set` objects (which will allow for `O(1)` membership tests):

```py
categories = {'animals': {'cat', 'dog', 'fish'},
              'colours': {'blue', 'green', 'red'},
              'food': {'beef', 'chips', 'pasta'},
              'sport': {'basketball', 'football', 'tennis'}}
```

Then iterate over the words and perform membership tests for each category set:

```py
def count_words(text, categories):
    counts = dict.fromkeys(categories, 0)
    for word in text:
        for cat_name, cat_words in categories.items():
            counts[cat_name] += word in cat_words
    return counts
```

Usage:

```py
In [19]: text = "Once upon a time there was a proper minimal reproducible example given by the OP without anybody having to ask for it".split()

In [20]: count_words(text, categories)
Out[20]: {'animals': 0, 'colours': 0, 'food': 0, 'sport': 0}

In [21]: text = ("cat dog fish "*3).split()

In [22]: count_words(text, categories)
Out[22]: {'animals': 9, 'colours': 0, 'food': 0, 'sport': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
animalOccurences = 0

for word in text:
    if word in animals:
        animalOccurences += 1
```

Here, I'm looping through every word in the `text` list and I check if that word is in the `animals` list. If it is then I add one to the `animalOccurences` variable